# Will lengthening our URLs change how Googlebot crawls our site?

Tags: url, web-crawlers, googlebot, clean-urls, crawl-rate

Currently we are using URL fetched from main title of article (55 characters). We are planning to increase title of article up to 100 characters which tends to increase length of URL to 100+.

Will this have a negative impact on Googlebot's crawling?

Comment: Are you just interested in crawling, or do you also want to know about indexing and ranking?

Comment: See also (opposite situation): [SEO - reducing URL length](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17233/seo-reducing-url-length) and [What effect does a URL length have on search engine indexing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79166/what-effect-does-a-url-length-have-on-search-engine-indexing)

Comment: Thanks for sharing information with Links. I wanted to know more about how Google bot interprets the URL & also its importance in its Crawling. I think once we know this we will understand more about indexing also.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't.

All you need to focus on is to make things easier for the end-user. 
Everything else doesn't matter anymore.

Google's algorithms are very evolved and what's good for the user is good for robots and ultimately for rankings.

Comment: I agree with your point that Google focuses on End user. But technically wanted to know more about Crawling.

Answer (score 2):

URL length does not have much impact on how Googlebot crawls.

Changing your URLs will have the biggest effect.  Googlebot will forever come back and crawl your old URLs.   You will need to implement redirects to the new URLs and maintain those redirects indefinitely.    If you change all your URLs, this can significantly increase the number of URLs that Googlebot needs to crawl.   It does not usually mean that Googlebot crawls fewer of your page URLs.  The redirect requests are so small and fast that they don't usually take away from your crawl budget much.

Comment: We are not in plan of changing the old URLs. We are planning to implement it on new URLs only. In that case how does it?

Comment: If you are not planning to redirect your old URLs, googlebot will come back and crawl the old URLs forever getting 404 errors.